# Define constant root project

Tags: php, autoload

in my Autoloader, i specify a root location for my classes:
but i'm getting this error when declaring the variable (in php7.0)

```
  protected static $pathTop = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/classes';
```

error is about this format, when trying with **ROOT**, also get a notice warning

err: *Constant expression contains invalid operations*

Comment: You can't define a property with a value that depends on the execution of functions.... set the value on instantiation

Comment: i see, it's expected like define('pathTop',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/classes') ?

Comment: That would work, although if you instantiate multiple autoloaders then you need to test if it's already been defined; and note that a static var is not a constant